# Automatically execute a macro when a cell value is changed by a DDE/OPC link

Tags: excel

I need to execute a macro when a cell value is changed by an external DDE/OPC link.  I've tried several of the examples using the Worksheet_Change function, but this only seems to work when a user types in a value (and even then, only works once).

Here's the entire code (after changing to the "Calculate" method):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()  'Calculate command will execute the macro when any value change the spreadsheet to recalculate
   Dim ctr As Integer, n1 As String, v1 As Single, trigger As Long

   'Application.EnableEvents = False
   'Workbooks("Data Save.xls").Select
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   trigger = Range("b5").Value  'data save trigger cell linked to PLC
   If trigger = 1 Then
      Dim fn1 As String
      fn1 = "C:\11047 RR\" & Range("B4") & ".csv"   'build a filename

      Open fn1 For Output As 1
      Print #1, Range("a1"); ","; Range("B1") 'batch number
      Print #1, Range("a2"); ","; Range("B2") 'part number
      Print #1, Range("a3"); ","; Range("B3") 'pass number
      Print #1, Range("a4"); ","; Range("B4") 'filename
      Print #1, "Date & Time:,"; Date$; ","; Time$
      For ctr = 7 To 69
         n1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ctr, 2).Value
         v1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ctr, 3).Value
         Print #1, ctr; ","; n1; ","; v1
      Next ctr
      Close 1
      Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 4) = 0   'put a zero into cell D5 in the spreadsheet
      RSIchan = DDEInitiate("RSLinx", "Upsetter_11047")
      DDEPoke RSIchan, "DataSaveFlag", Range("D5") 'write cell D5 out to the trigger word
      DDETerminate (RSIchan)
      MsgBox "Data saved"
      Application.EnableEvents = True


   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Calculate** event.  Say cell A1 gets refreshed via DDE.  In another cell (say B1), enter:

=A1

When A1 gets refreshed, B1 will get re-calculated and the **Calculate** event will be tripped.

**EDIT #1** :

The workbook is calculated as soon as the workbook is opened.  That means the Event macro also gets triggered as so as the workbook is opened.  Now if B5 initially contains text rather than a number or is empty, then you will get the error message you see.

For example, starting with a blank worksheet, place a single space in B5 and run:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim t As Long
    t = Range("B5").Value
End Sub
```

You should see an error 13.

**EDIT #2**:

In your posted code, replace:

```
trigger = Range("b5").Value
```

with:

```
 Dim V As Variant
    V = Range("B5").Value
    If IsNumeric(V) Then
        trigger = CLng(V)
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But it leads to another issue I don't understand. When I first load the spreadsheet, I immediately get a Run-time error 13 "Type mismatch". When I click on "Debug", it takes me to the following line: trigger = Range("b5").Value  (I've tried it with and without the .Value, and tried integer and long as data types in the Dim statement).  In spite of this error message, it still seems to work, and the error only pops up once.  Any ideas?

Comment: Code is now posted above.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the line of code, it may be a problem with the initial value in B5.  See my **EDIT** above

Comment: The cell isn't empty when it first loads. I tried adding an If..Then statement to check if it's empty, but that didn't work either.  Also tried adding Val() around the Range statement.

Comment: B5 has a link to another program (called RSLinx) which reads data from a PLC (machine controller).  Usually has a zero in it.  I also tried using C5 instead of B5, where C5 had "=B5" in it, thinking that maybe Excel would be happier using its own expression instead of the DDE/OPC link.

Comment: That works. Thanks!  (I'd like to give you a "helpful vote", but apparently I'm not worthy.... and I add too many comments.)